# Call button clicked method in parent class in swift

Tags: class, button, swift

I have a ViewController that calls a class to build a menu. This menu draw a button with a buttonClicked method. I call this menu from many different ViewControllers so I need this menu to call a different button method depending on the ViewController it was called from. I cannot think how to program this?

```
class MenuController : UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         var menu = Menu()
         self.view.addSubview(menu)
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
    {
        var tag = sender.tag
        println("I want the button click method to call this method")
    }
}

class Menu:UIView
{
    init()
    {
        var button:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,280, 25)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.tag = Int(itemNo)
        menu.addSubview(button)
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
    {
        var tag = sender.tag
        println(tag)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for either a closure or a delegate/protocol:

**Closure option**

In your Menu class, create a public variable (say `buttonCode`) that will host your closure:

```
class Menu:UIView
{
  var buttonCode : ()->()
```

and your `buttonClicked` function becomes:

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
  self.buttonCode()
}
```

Then in the controller, you set up `menu.buttonCode = { println("hello") }`, and that's it.

**Protocol option**

You create a protocol for your Menu, that expects a `buttonCode()` function. You also create a var in the Menu class to host the weak reference for the delegate. Your view controller implements the protocol and the `buttonCode()` function. Then your `buttonClicked` function becomes:

```
func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
  self.delegate.buttonCode()
}
```

I personally prefer today to use the closure option, it's cleaner and simpler, at least in this situation. Please see http://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/2ces1q/closures_vs_delegates/ for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: Brilliant! That was exactly what I needed and it fixed my problem perfectly. The thought that came to me in the night was to subclass Menu() and then override the buttonClicked method, but your way works nicely. BTW that was a very nicely answered question; thank you for taking the time to answer it for me.